Websocket connect, but cannot listen/receive a message in Next js 14 App Router
websocket postman testing
i am creating a websocket project that uses next js and nest js as API. When tested in Postman, the websocket process managed to run normally, but when connected to the browser, the websocket connected successfully but I couldn't receive event messages from the server.
Nest js API
@WebSocketGateway(2020, {
    path: "/trip-monitoring",
    cors: {
        origin: "*",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    }
})
export class TripMonitoringGateway implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
    @WebSocketServer() server: Server;
    constructor(private readonly tripsService: TripsService) { }

    afterInit(server: any) {
        console.log('WebSocket initialized');
    }

    async handleConnection(client: any, ...args: any[]) {
        console.log('Client connected:', client.id);

    }

    handleDisconnect(client: any) {
        console.log('Client disconnected:', client.id);
    }

    // for wss
    @SubscribeMessage('tripMonitoring')
    handleAddTripMonitoring(@MessageBody() addTripMonitoringRequestDTO: AddTripMonitoringRequestDTO): Observable<WsResponse<any>> {
        // Handle the incoming data, e.g., save to database
        console.log(`Data received: `, addTripMonitoringRequestDTO);

        // Validate and save data to the database
        return from(this.tripsService.addTripMonitoring(addTripMonitoringRequestDTO)).pipe(
            map(trip => ({ event: 'tripMonitoringEvent', data: trip }))
        );
    }
}

Next js Connection
useEffect(() => {
        const websocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:2020/trip-monitoring');

        websocket.onopen = () => {
            console.log('WebSocket is connected');
        };

        // notting happen here
        websocket.addEventListener('tripMonitoringEvent', (event: any) => {
            const message = event.data;
            console.log('Received message:', message);
        });

        websocket.onclose = () => {
            console.log('WebSocket is closed');
        };

        return () => {
            websocket.close();
        };
    }, []);

I also attached the testing process in Postman which is running normally.
Maybe there is something from Next js that I missed or got wrong, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Next js App can listen/receive any event message from websocket
